# Cypher Neo4j query optimization

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I use the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (v:Value)-[:CONTAINS]->(hv:HistoryValue) 
WHERE v.id = {valueId} 
OPTIONAL MATCH (hv)-[:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
WHERE {fetchCreateUsers} 
WITH u, hv 
ORDER BY hv.createDate DESC 
WITH count(hv) as count, ceil(toFloat(count(hv)) / {maxResults}) as step, COLLECT({userId: u.id, historyValueId: hv.id, historyValue: hv.originalValue, historyValueCreateDate: hv.createDate}) AS data 
RETURN REDUCE(s = [], i IN RANGE(0, count - 1, CASE step WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE step END) | s + data[i]) AS result, step, count
```

This query works fine and does exactly what I need.

Right now I'm concerned about two possible issues inside of this query from the performance point of view and Cypher best practices.

First of all, as you may see -  I two times use the same `count(hv)` function. Will it cause the problems during the execution from the performance point of view or Cypher and Neo4j are smart enough to optimize it? If no, please show how to fix it.

And the second place is the `CASE` statement inside range() function? The same question here - will this `CASE` statement be executed only once or every time for every iteration over my range? Please show how to fix it if needed.

**UPDATED**

I tried to do a separator WITH for count but the query doesn't return the results(returns empty result)

```
MATCH (v:Value)-[:CONTAINS]->(hv:HistoryValue) 
WHERE v.id = {valueId} 
OPTIONAL MATCH (hv)-[:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
WHERE {fetchCreateUsers} 
WITH u, hv ORDER BY hv.createDate DESC 
WITH u, hv, count(hv) as count 
WITH u, hv, count, ceil(toFloat(count) / {maxResults}) as step, COLLECT({userId: u.id, historyValueId: hv.id, historyValue: hv.originalValue, historyValueCreateDate: hv.createDate}) AS data 
RETURN REDUCE(s = [], i IN RANGE(0, count - 1, CASE step WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE step END) | s + data[i]) AS result, step, count
```

Comment: Do a separate `WITH count(hv) AS, ...` before the next `WITH`.

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas please see my updated question. It doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: The problem is the inclusion of `hv`, so the query cannot do a meaningful aggregation. Use `WITH u, count(hv) as count`

Comment: This way I have the following exception: `org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Variable hv not defined (line 1, column 214 (offset: 213))`

Comment: Remove subsequent usage of `hv`. Also, please update your query in the question.

Comment: If I remove hv, I'm getting the exception above. Honestly, I don't understand how  it can be removed

Comment: Well, it turns out it cannot really be removed, as you're collecting `hv`'s fields later. I think the only option you have left is `WITH u, collect(hv) AS hvs, count(hv) as count UNWIND hvs AS hv`, which is not very elegant and a lot of hassle to get rid of a duplication.

Comment: Have you tried running PROFILE on the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1 MATCH (v:Value)-[:CONTAINS]->(hv:HistoryValue) 
2 WHERE v.id = {valueId} 
3 OPTIONAL MATCH (hv)-[:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
4 WHERE {fetchCreateUsers} 
5 WITH u, hv 
6 ORDER BY hv.createDate DESC 
7 WITH count(hv) as count, ceil(toFloat(count(hv)) / {maxResults}) as step, COLLECT({userId: u.id, historyValueId: hv.id, historyValue: hv.originalValue, historyValueCreateDate: hv.createDate}) AS data 
8 RETURN REDUCE(s = [], i IN RANGE(0, count - 1, CASE step WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE step END) | s + data[i]) AS result, step, count
```

(1) You need to pass `hv` in line 5, because it's values are collected in line 7. That said, you can still do something like this:

```
5 WITH u, collect(hv) AS hvs, count(hv) as count
  UNWIND hvs AS hv
```

However, this is not very elegant and probably not worth doing.

(2) You can calculate the `CASE` expression in line 7:

```
7 WITH count, data, step, CASE step WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE step END AS stepFlag
8 RETURN REDUCE(s = [], i IN RANGE(0, count - 1, stepFlag) | s + data[i]) AS result, step, count
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there any sense from the performance point of view to calculate the CASE expression in line 7 or it is just a syntax sugar?

Comment: I don't think there is a measurable difference. Query times are mostly dominated by disc access or, if the related parts of the graph are already in memory, the more complex operations (matching, calculating aggregations, etc.).